# Card Game - Probability amongst players with different hand size

Tags: probability, card-games

The game involves a standard deck of 52 cards and 2 jokers (54 cards total) and 4 players.

Two players receive 14 cards and the other 2 players receive 13 cards and these hands are assigned at random

Imagine you are one of these players and receive one of the hands described....

What is the probability the hand you are dealt contains no jokers?

---

I took this approach:

**sample space** = |ohm| = ( 54 choose 13 ) + ( 54 choose 14 )

54 being all the total cards to select from and having an equal chance to get 12 or 13 cards...

**numerator** = |A| = ( 54 - 2 choose 13 ) + ( 54 - 2 choose 14 )

54 total cards - 2 jokers ...

Is this the correct approach? I got a probability of about using P = |A|/|ohm| .. 0.55219

Thanks

Comment: What is the chance you receive one of the $14$ card hands?  What is the chance of a $13$ card hand?  No, your approach will not be correct.  Remember that $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$ is only valid if each outcome in the sample space is equally likely to occur.  Instead, you should condition your calculations based on whether you have a $13$ card hand or a $14$ card hand and approach each case individually.

Comment: oh i see... Is there a more appropriate method to use to incorporate both cases into a single probability?

Comment: $\Pr(A) = \Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)+\Pr(A\mid B^c)\Pr(B^c)$.  If you are asking about using a single *counting argument*, no.  Conditional probability is the way to go.